# Angular. How to check is user url real?

Tags: angular

Hi) I have a question about Angular. I have a form where user input price of prize and its url. I need to check if this url exists and valid before he submit form.

I thought about get request and checking response in this way:

```
checkUrl(index: number): boolean {
    let isUrlValid = false;
    const url = this.prizesForm.getRawValue()[index].url;
    const params = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type'
      })
    };
    this.http.get(url, params).subscribe((res: Response) => {
      if (res.ok) {
        isUrlValid = true;
      }
    });
    return isUrlValid;
  }
```

But it doesnt work, because of CORS. Maybe someone know another solution?
Will be appreciate for any advices)

Comment: Maybe, make `Submit` a two step process, first step will send a `HEAD` request, if that is successful, then it will send your `GET` request

Comment: You can try to pass url to your back-end, it will make a call to the url without cors limitation and then allow user to submit form

Comment: Thanks) Will try!